# regex for finding all money values

Tags: regex

so im trying to find all possible money values.

i need to find things like

£100bn
$100m
30p
100m euro
100bn euros

etc

so far i have

```
(?:[\£\$\€]?\{1}[,\d]+.?\d*[p|m|(bn)][euros]?)
```

but i cant seem to get it to work. please help

this currently doesnt find any of the given money values, i have tried regex101.com and i cant seem to get an explanation as to why it wont catch any of the values

Comment: You need to give us much more information if we are to help. What's not working?  Is this in a program? What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Have you tried inputting your regex for instance at `https://regex101.com/`? You will get a very detailed explaination of what your regex currently does. For instance because of the `\{1}` in your regex, it requires your string to *literally*  contain `{1}` ...

Comment: Escaping the brace is definitely not ok. Remove the backslash from your first curly brace.  Then you are forcing the 1 quantifier on a non greedy target. So either remove the question mark or put a capture group around the first statement and move the question mark behind the group. then you should start matching something :)

Like this (?:([\£\$\€]{1})?[,\d]+.?\d*[p|m|(bn)][euros]?)

Comment: hey, thats close, it still doesnt catch some of the things though

Comment: I was hoping it would get you up to speed and that you would finish it. See my answer then. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Escaping the first curly brace is probably not what you want. Once you remove the backslash you will notice, that something is not right.

So you want to make sure that the currency symbol occurs only once and also that only IF it occurs. So I would suggest making a capture group out of your first target and make the whole group non greedy

`([\£\$\€]{1})?`

Fixing this already captures all values containing numbers. Capturing the values where the currency is stated as a word, I would just add space into your last group and use star `*` instead of `?` making the regex look like this

`(([\£\$\€]{1})?[,\d]+.?\d*[p|m|(bn)][ euros]*)`

Lastly I would make the p|m|... group non greedy (probably you might want it not to be greedy) so I would put a question mark there too. So the final regex could look like this

`(([\£\$\€]{1})?[,\d]+.?\d*[p|m|(bn)]?[ euros]*)`

**EDIT**

After reading the comments, let us accept only valid numbers by replacing `[,\d]+.?\d*` with `(\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.\d+)?`
Then you might want to explicitly match only on p|m|bn and you can do that by using `(bn|m|p)?` instead of `[p|m|(bn)]?`
lastly you must capture the correct order of the letters in the word euro(s) and take the leading space into account `( euros?)?` so your "final" regex could look like this `(([\£\$\€]{1})?(\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.\d+)?(bn|m|p)?( euros?)?)`

Now you have learnt enough about regexes and feel free to extend or limit it to your likings.

Comment: that works great, only problem is it catches things that arent needed like random commas and stuff, any idea how to stop that?

Comment: `.` matches any character. If you literally want a `.` use `\.` instead ...  `[,\d]+`  matches any sequence consisting of commas and digits. Do you need thousands separators? If yes, then you have to care for proper grouping (ie a `,` must only occur every three digits), if no, remove the `,` from the regex. Furthermore `[ euros]*` will also match a string like `"   o s e u   "` which is obviously not what you want. And if all that erroneous results have been resolved, you regex will still accept a string like "$500bn euros", which is again obviously not correct ...

Comment: You are explicitly trying to catch them [,\d]+.?  so I wouldn't know that you don't want to match them

Comment: Your final regex is still leaving the most complex part unresolved. How to prevent matching a string like `$500bn euros`